# Filtering Column based on values on Another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'am tying to get the specific columns whose name starts with some patterns.

table_1

```
abcA| abcB | abcC | xyD | mnE

1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10

11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15
```

From the above table i'am in need of the Output Like

```
abcA | abcB | abcC

1 | 2 | 3

6 | 7 | 8

11 | 12 | 13
```

The columns should be selected DYNAMICALLY by filtering like any column name starts with abc should me selected.

I Tried this Query

```
"select column_name from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='table_1' and column_name like 'abc%';"
```

It gives a another table only with column names

column_name

```
abcA

abcB

abcC
```

But I want to get the values of that Column names.

Thanks

Comment: @Shadow I am reopening because the link you gave talks about how to do what the OP is trying to do, which in fact is bad practice, and ought not to be done.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen which is pointed out both in comments and the accepted answer of the duplicate question. But you had to get your answer in at all costs...

Answer (score 2):

This is poor table design, and it is fairly difficult to write code which can select a dynamic column name.  Here is the design I would suggest to you:

```
ID  | name | pos
1   | abcA | 1
2   | abcB | 1
3   | abcC | 1
4   | xyD  | 1
5   | mnE  | 1
6   | abcA | 2
7   | abcB | 2
8   | abcC | 2
9   | xyD  | 2
10  | mnE  | 2
11  | abcA | 3
12  | abcB | 3
13  | abcC | 3
14  | xyD  | 3
15  | mnE  | 3
```

With this design in place, you only need a very simple query:

```
SELECT pos, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) AS ids
FROM yourTable
WHERE name LIKE 'abc%'
GROUP BY pos;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the design. Please go through it suggest some solution.